# Current_user && User profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

So in my To-do app I have profiles for each user that displays a list of all the Items they have created like so :

```
<% if current_user %>
<h1>Hello, <%= current_user.username.capitalize%>, </h1>
<% else %>
<h1><%= @user.username.capitalize%> To - Do List. </h1>
<%end %>

<h4> List of Items </h4>
<%= render :partial => 'items/form', :locals =>{:item => Item.new} %>
<% @user.items.order('created_at DESC').each do |item| %>
<%= render :partial => 'items/item' , :locals => {:item => item } %>
<% end %>
```

My problem is that I want users to be able view other Users profile but with the Header changing according to who is viewing it.

`<h1>Hello, <%= current_user.username.capitalize%>, Here is your To-do Items</h1>`

if its the current_users own profile  or:

`<h1><%= @user.username.capitalize%> To - Do List. </h1>`

if the user is viewing another users profile.

As you can see I tried a little something with an if statement but it doesn't seem to be working as i want it to .Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try current_user == @user in if condition.

If there is a possibility that current_user could be nil, then

Try current_user.present? && current_user == @user in if condition.

Comment: Thank you this did it i kept trying `<%current_user && @user  %> `

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you may have:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

---

Then in your view something along the line of

```
<% if current_user == @user %>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code:

```
 current_user == @user if condition.
```